# PUPPET - linux domain machines cert error

Tags: linux, certificate, puppet

At my workplace we have some computer labs. In these laboratories each computer has the operating system windows and linux. Both systems are in our AD domain.

I did a lab of tests and I have a functional puppet server. I put some nodes/agents as root and Everything working perfectly when I run `puppet agent -t`.

**The problem:**

When I log in with a domain user (e.g: xiru) on linux machines and run the `puppet agent -t` command, a new certificate is generated, but an error occurs warning that it does not match the server's certificate.

For the domain users, the puppet creates the new certificate on the path: `/home/<user>/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl`

Linux machines names in the test:

- mint-client.mycompany.intra
- ubuntu-client.mycompany.intra

I try set `certname` variable on the puppet conf, but the error remains.

```
[main]
certname = mint-client.mycompany.intra

[agent]
server = puppet.mycompany.intra
```

How can I get around this and make it always with the same certificate that I configure via root user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must setup your environtment to accept non-root users.

When you run it, do you use sudo or the users are present on sudoers?

If its not, on puppet docs theres some tips to run it as non-root users...

> Installation and configuration
>
> To properly configure non-root agent access, you need to:
>
> ```
> Install a monolithic PE master
> Install and configure PE agents, disable the puppet service on all nodes, and create non-root users
> Verify the non-root configuration
> ```
>
> Install and configure a monolithic master
>
> ```
> As a root user, install and configure a monolithic PE master. Use the web-based installer or the text-mode installer.
>
> Use the PE console to make sure no new agents can get added to the MCollective group.
>
>   a. In the console, click Nodes > Classification, and in the PE Infrastructure group, select the PE MCollective group.
>
>   b. On the Rules tab, under Fact, locate aio_agent_version and click Remove.
>
>   c. Commit changes.
> ```
>
> Install and configure PE agents and create non-root users
>
> ```
> 1. On each agent node, install a PE agent while logged in as a root user. Refer to the instructions for installing agents.
>
> 2. As a root user, log in to an agent node, and add the non-root user with puppet resource user <UNIQUE NON-ROOT USERNAME> ensure=present managehome=true.
>
>   Note: Each and every non-root user must have a unique name.
>
> 3. As a root user, still on the agent node, set the non-root user’s password. For example, on most *nix systems run passwd
> ```
>
> ```
> 4. By default, the puppet service runs automatically as a root user, so it needs to be disabled. As a root user on the agent node, stop the service by running puppet resource service puppet ensure=stopped enable=false.
>
> 5. Disable the MCollective service on the agent node. As a root user, run puppet resource service mcollective ensure=stopped enable=false.
>
> 6. Disable the PXP agent.
>
>   a. In the console, click Nodes > Classification* and in the PE Infrastructure group, select the PE Agent group.
>
>   b. On the Classes tab, select the puppet_enterprise::profile::agent class, and set the parameter pxp_enabled to false.
>
> 7. Change to the non-root user.
>
>   Tip: If you wish to use su - <NON-ROOT USERNAME> to switch between accounts, make sure to use the - (-l in some unix variants) argument so that full login privileges are correctly granted. Otherwise you may see “permission denied” errors when trying to apply a catalog.
>
> 8. As the non-root user, generate and submit the cert for the agent node. From the agent node, execute the following command:
>
>     puppet agent -t --certname "<UNIQUE NON-ROOT USERNAME.HOSTNAME>" --server "<PUPPET MASTER HOSTNAME>"
>
>   This Puppet run submits a cert request to the master and creates a ~/.puppet directory structure in the non-root user’s home directory.
>
> 9. As an admin user, log into the console, navigate to the pending node requests, and accept the requests from non-root user agents.
>
>   Note: It is possible to also sign the root user certificate in order to allow that user to also manage the node. However, you should do so only with great caution as this introduces the possibility of unwanted behavior and potential security issues. For example, if your site.pp has no default node configuration, running agent as non-admin could lead to unwanted node definitions getting generated using alt hostnames, which is a potential security issue. In general, if you deploy this   scenario, you should ensure that the root and non-root users never try to manage the same resources,ensure that they have clear-cut node definitions, and ensure that classes scope correctly. As the non-root user, run puppet config set certname <UNIQUE NON-ROOT USERNAME.HOSTNAME> --section agent.
>
> 10. As the non-root user, run puppet config set server <PUPPET MASTER HOSTNAME> --section agent. Steps 7 and 8 create and set the configuration for the non-root agent’s puppet.conf, created in /.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ in the non-root user’s home directory.
>
>   [main]
>   certname = <UNIQUE NON-ROOT USERNAME.HOSTNAME>
>   server = <PUPPET MASTER HOSTNAME>
>
> 11. You can now connect the non-root agent node to the master and get PE to configure it. Log into the agent node as the non-root user and run puppet agent -t.
> ```

Source: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.1/deploy_nonroot-agent.html

Comment: Kelson, thanks for the answer!!

I had already visualized this link, but I use the puppet open source and the tutorial is for the puppet enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions. To make it work, you can provide relevant permissions to the folder where certificates are stored, so that domain user has permissions on the certificates.